# How to select a special div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

my HTML code looks like this. (I have a special design of radio input)

```
<div class="area" id="area-1">
 <div class="input">
  <input type="radio" class="active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio>
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="area" id="area-2">
 <div class="input">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio>
  <input type="radio" class="active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I click on a radio in "#area-1", I want to remove the class "active-radio" on the others radio in "area-1" but not in "area-2".

*There are a lot of div .area so I don't want to specify each time the div id in my script.*

JS:

```
var thisArea = this.closest(".area");
$(thisArea + " .input input[type='radio']").parent().removeClass('active-radio').addClass('no-active-radio');
$(this).addClass('active-radio').removeClass('no-active-radio');
```

Basically I want to select all the .input which contain a radio input in the same .area as the clicked radio.

I think the problem come from this part :

```
thisArea + " .input input[type='radio']"
```

Comment: Is it just a typo that the closing quotes are left off the `no-active-radio` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate a jQuery object and a string. Use `.find()` to find the elements that match the selector. Also, the `active-radio` class isn't on the parents of the radio buttons, it's on the radio buttons themselves, so don't use `.parent()`.

```
thisArea.find(".input :radio").removeClass('active-radio').addClass('no-active-radio');
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$(thisArea)
  .find(".input input[type='radio']")
  .parent()
  .removeClass('active-radio')
  .addClass('no-active-radio');
```

Comment: No need for `$()` around `thisArea`, it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes this will work, but `$()` redundant here. @buildok

Answer (score 0):

Limit your search context to the clicked element.

```js
Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('.area'))
  .forEach( a => a.addEventListener('click', clickFun, false) );


function clickFun(e) {
  Array
    .from(e.target.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]'))
    .forEach( a => {
      a.classList.toggle('no-active-radio');
      a.classList.toggle('active-radio');
    })
  };
```

```css
.area { 
  display:block;
  background-color:#a0a0a0;
  padding:20px;
  margin:20px;
 }

input[type=radio].active-radio { 
  zoom:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="area" id="area-1">
 <div class="input">
  <input type="radio" class="active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="area" id="area-2">
 <div class="input">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="active-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="no-active-radio">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thisArea.find('input[type="radio"]').removeClass('active-radio');
$(this).addClass('active-radio');
```

*Unless you are having different css styles on radio inputs and different styles on radio inputs with a no-active class then there is no point in having the no-active class. Just add and remove the active class and add the styles of the no-active class directly to the input[type="radio'] in the css.